# How to check version of nodemon installed locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodemon

I installed nodemon locally in a project on my windows 10 machine. I want to check what version was installed. What is the command to check the version installed? I did not install globally as i am just learning how to use nodejs and express. The command i found was to check globally installed version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways by which you can check the versions of any packages you have installed locally

1.Goto package.json, if you have it installed as a production dependency, find the package name in the dependencies section. And if you have installed it as a development dependency, find the package name in the devDependencies section of package.json

alternatively

2.You can just do a `$ npm list` in your terminal inside the project folder. If you want to check all the globally installed packages, you can do a `$ npm list -g` from anywhere.